# AttributeError: module 'feedparser' has no attribute 'FeedParserDict'

Tags: python, feedparser

I am trying to `import feedparser` in Python, and want to call FeedParserDict from the library feedparser, i.e., `feedparser.FeedParserDict`. But it leads to the following error:

"AttributeError: module 'feedparser' has no attribute 'FeedParserDict'."

Does it mean that "FeedParserDict" is not in the library feedparser ([version 5.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser)). I find that "FeedParserDict" is present in previous version of feedparser (i.e., [version 3.3](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/changes-33.html)). How can I cope with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've `pip install feedparser==5.2.1` and "FeedParserDict" is present in it

```
import feedparser

print(feedparser.__version__)
print(feedparser.FeedParserDict)
```

output:

```
5.2.1
<class 'feedparser.FeedParserDict'>
```

Comment: When I execute above python code, I find the same problem. But if I install "feedparser" by "pip install feedparser==5.2.1" instead of "python setup.py install", the problem is resolved. So it seems that it is more formal to install Lib by "pip" in Python?

Comment: Whenever you need a new package always try to install it via pip first